# Animated 2D heat map

Tags: numpy, heatmap, matplotlib-animation

I have a function `u(x,y,z,t)` and I wanted to plot `(x,y)` animated heatmap with colorbar (u_min, u_max) where `t` is parameter for time animation. I've analyzed the examples, but it looks complicated. The `z` parameter will be constant. The defined `u(x,y,z,t)` is the equation
[u(x,y,z,t)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAShG.gif).

I made this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def u(x, y, z, t):

   alpha = 9*10**-6
   a = 0.01
   z = a/2


   for i in range(1,k):

       sin1 = np.sin((i*np.pi*x)/a)

       sin2 = np.sin((i*np.pi*y)/a)

       sin3 = np.sin((i*np.pi*z)/a)

       e = np.exp(-((alpha**2)*(np,pi**2)*((n**2)*(m**2)*(l**2))*t/a**2)

       a_n = 80*(2/np.pi)**3*(1/n*m*l)*(1-(-1)**n)*(1-(-1)**m)*(1-(-1)**l)

       u += 20 + a_n*sin1*sin2*sin3*e

    return u

data = u

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for j in range(len(data)):
    ax.cla()
    ax.imshow(data[j])
    ax.set_title("frame {}".format(i))
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: [This](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/animation_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-animation-animation-demo-py) may solve your problem. Reference.

Comment: I explained more in post.

Comment: Isn't this what we need to get the function working? Let's try a lot of things.`ax.imshow(u(x,y,z,t,j))`